# JTextArea/JScrollPane Stutters When Scrolling

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have noticed that the JTextArea does not scroll smoothly, like a UITextArea would. It appears that when I scroll down, it jumps to the next line, not smoothly scrolling over the text.

I have created an animated GIF of the problem here:
[image: window scrolling]

Example Code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
frame.setLayout(bl);

JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(6, 30);
textArea.setText(TEXT_FOR_TEXT_AREA);
JScrollPane textScroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);

frame.add(textScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Is there a way to make the scrolling more smooth (and not cut the text perfectly, line-by-line)?

Thanks.

Comment: An animatied gif doesn't help us since the problem is likely with your code. Post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This is a standard JTextArea in a JScrollPane with no extra modifications, I have posted example code.

Comment: That is NOT a SSCCE. I cannot copy/paste/compile/execute that code. `and not cut the text perfectly,` - should create the text area by using `new JTextArea(6, 30)` so the text area will be sized to display exactly 6 lines of text when you pack() the frame. Maybe this is an APPPLE feature. In Windows I can see partial lines.

Comment: @JakeChasan The example code scrolls smoothly for me. Am running it using build 1.8.0-b132 on Windows 7

Comment: I am using build 1.8.0_5-b13, but I have seen this happen even in JRE7, is there a method that does not require the scroll pane to hide the entire line when a user scrolls?

Comment: `is there a method that does not require the scroll pane to hide the entire line when a user scrolls? ` - maybe this is an APPLE feature. I see partial lines when I scroll. I'm use JDK7 on Windows 7.

Comment: @JakeChasan when you say "scroll" how exactly are you scrolling?

Comment: I have a Magic Mouse and on the Mac, when you scroll, it has a scroll bounce when you scroll to low or too high, and when you are scrolling, you can view partial lines. Possibly this is only happening on my computer. IDK. When you scroll by dragging the scrollbar, it scrolls fine, but when you scroll with the mouse, that is when it is not smooth.

Comment: @JakeChasan That is the limitation of the mouse scroll, it is impossible for it to scroll smoothly. You can adjust the resolution of the scrolling via `<ScrollPane>.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement()` but that also affects the speed of the scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help, that is interesting that Oracle did not fix this limitation in JRE8.

Comment: `that is interesting that Oracle did not fix this limitation in JRE8` - what limitation? There is no limitation to fix. Each Swing component attempts to determine what a reasonable scrolling unit should be. For a JTextArea it is the height on one line of text. For a JTable is is one row of data. If you don't like the default behaviour you change it in one line of code.

Comment: You are right, upon further discussion, it appears that this is not a limitation. I was just hoping that Oracle would try to make the Swing UI as seamless with the Mac UI as possible. Why do you think that increasing the scroll unit decreases the scroll speed, if a native app scrolls with a very fine unit at the same speed that JScrollPane would have scrolled?

Comment: never seen that, for reasonable lenght and plain text, sure there can be bunch of whitespace chars (>30-50pct) that isn't diplayable in JTextArea, causing by broken XxxView

Comment: `Why do you think that increasing the scroll unit decreases the scroll speed,` - I didn't make that comment, what I think vandale meant was that when you scroll you will still generate the same number of events. If for each event you scroll the viewport 8 pixels instead of 16 it will appear to be slower.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. Is there any way to make the events fire at faster intervals? Or are they firing at the speed of the JavaVM?